# Fluent NHibernate + Multiple Databases = Fluently.Configure() mapping to the wrong database?

Tags: session, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, factory

So I have a static class that is used for creating a dictionary of NHibernate ISessionFactories (I need one for each database/dialect I access). Now I must be missing something, because while my code works 100% for a single database, trying to configure second database fails, and it turns out it's because somehow it's still mapping to the initial database (I confirmed this by adding a table from my new database to my old one, and watched it work). Here is my code (notes will follow):

```
  public static class NHibernateFactory {
    private static Dictionary<String, ISessionFactory> _sessionFactory = new Dictionary<String, ISessionFactory>();

    public static void Initialize(Assembly assembly, String ConnectionStringKey) {
      if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKey] != null) {
        IPersistenceConfigurer dbConnection = null;
        switch (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringKey].ProviderName.ToLower()) {
          .
          . Various cases here for each type of database/dialect
          .
          case "system.data.sqlite":
            switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConnectionStringKey].ToLower()) {
              case "standard": dbConnection = SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(ConnectionStringKey));
              break;
            }
          break;
          .
          .
          .
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
          _sessionFactory.Add(ConnectionStringKey, Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
              dbConnection
            )
            .Mappings(m => {
              m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
            })
            .BuildSessionFactory()
          );
        }
      }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession(String ConnectionStringKey) {
      return _sessionFactory[ConnectionStringKey].OpenSession();
    }

  }
```

Now, I know for certain that the proper assembly and connectionstringkey are getting passed in. And I can see that dbConnection is getting set properly as well. So it's completely baffling to me that it fails on m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly); with a "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory." error message.

Like I said, after tracing it, it appears to be due to the fact somewhere along the line it's still referencing the DB from the initial configuration. Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? Perhaps there is something I'm misunderstanding.

Does anyone have an example of setting up Fluent NHibernate for use with multiple distinct databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysteriously, with zero changes to the code, this has started to work. If appears it might have been a caching issue with Visual Studio 2010's development webserver (as this is part of a WCF service which is being hosting in an ASP.NET application).